# How can I calculate the total of something on an attribute through "hasMany"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to setup a basic system so I can learn laravel.

I've got 5 models:

Donation and Invoice - the same thing but with different attributes.

It has many payments

Payments - representing a paypal payment someone might make towards their invoice/donation.

Invoice_Payments/Donation_Payments - representing a link between a payment an an invoice (2 columns - invoice_id/donation_id and payment_id)

I'm trying to write a function called calcInvoicePaid which takes an input of the Invoice and returns the total amount of all the payments made towards it but I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: invoice_payments.id (SQL: select "payments".*, "invoice_payments"."invoice_id" from "payments" inner join "invoice_payments" on "invoice_payments"."id" = "payments"."invoice_payment_id" where "invoice_payments"."invoice_id" = 4) (View: C:\...\paymenow\app\views\admin\index.blade.php)
```

Here is my Invoice model

```
<?php

class Invoice extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'invoices';

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Payment', 'InvoicePayment');
    }

    public static function calcInvoicePaid($item)
    {
        $count = 0;
        foreach($item->payments as $payment) {
            $count += $payment->amount;
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

and my Invoice_Payment migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateInvoicePaymentsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('invoice_payments', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices');
            $table->integer('payment_id')->references('id')->on('payments');
            $table->primary(array('invoice_id', 'payment_id'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('invoice_payments');
    }

}
```

and my Payments migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePaymentsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->float('amount');
            $table->integer('type'); //code: 0 = manual, 1 = paypal
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('payments');
    }

}
```

Could anyone explain to me what I've done wrong? Apologies if it's a noob question - I've not got any experience in Laravel and only a little in MVC as a whole.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not `hasManyThrough`, it's many-to-many relation with pivot table, ie. `belongsToMany`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk how would it be belongsToMany? Invoice hasMany Payments; each payment is owned by 1 invoice (same for donations)

Comment: Once again: *Invoice_Payments/Donation_Payments - representing a link between a payment an an invoice* - so you're saying there is a pivot table between invoices and payments, and donations and payments.

Answer (score 0):

What you said what you *want* and what you *did* are different things. You said, you want a `hasMany` relation, but instead you created a pivot table and thus a `belongsToMany` relation.

The solution:

Remove the `invoice_payments` table altogether and add an `invoice_id` to the `payments` table. Then change the relation in the `Invoice` model like so:

```
public function payments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Payment');
}
```

You can then create payments towards an invoice with

```
$invoice->payments()->save(new Payment(Input::all()));
```

Comment: As for the solution `1` - definitely unreal setup. Payment definitely may cover several invoices.

Comment: I think I've still confused people - An invoice can have multiple payments towards it. Eg. If I bill you for $1500 you might pay $500 now, then another $750 etc...

Comment: A payment will not be assigned to multiple invoices, though.

Comment: So my solution works. One invoice has multiple payments (just like OP wants). And in reality, there is rarely a case where I pay multiple invoices with only one payment.

Comment: @sisou The pivot table is needed because a payment can be either for a donation or an invoice. Maybe I should simplify it and have Donation as an invoice type.

Comment: I see. So you really have a *polymorphic* relation. Where both the Invoice and the Donation have Payments. So you need a polymorhpic has-many relation, as described here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships (search the page for `Polymorphic Relations`. You'll want to look at the example with the photos and `imageable`.